# How to save data in a table from observer in magento?

Tags: magento-1, event-observer

The given below is my code, by which I am able to save data in database. It is working because I am extending `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` in observer file. However I don't want to extend the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` file in observer file. Is their any other way to save data from observer?

The given below is my code where I declared observer in config file:

```
<global>
       <models>
           <User_Tracker>
               <class>User_Tracker_Model</class>
           </User_Tracker>
       </models>
       <events>
           <sales_order_place_after>
               <observers>
                   <User_Tracker>
                       <type>singleton</type>
                       <class>User_Tracker/observer</class>
                       <method>customOrderSave</method>
                   </User_Tracker>
               </observers>
           </sales_order_place_after>
       </events>
   </global>
```

and the given below is my `Observer.php` inside model folder through which I save data in table:

```
class User_Tracker_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
  {
    public function _construct()
     {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('tracker/observer');
     }
    public function customOrderSave($observer)
     {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();        
      $customer_name = $order->getCustomerName();
      $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
      $shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getShippingAddress()->getId());
      $company = $shippingAddress->getCompany(); 
      $street = $shippingAddress->getStreet();
      $phone = $shippingAddress->getTelephone();
      $city = $shippingAddress->getCity();
      $zip = $shippingAddress->getPostcode();
      $region = $shippingAddress->getRegion();
      $address = implode(" ",$street);
      $order_date = Date("d/m/y");
      foreach ($ordered_items as $item)
       {
        $product_id = $item->getProductId();
        $product_price = $item->getPrice();
        $product_tax = $item->getTax();
        $product_name = $item->getName();
        $orderedQty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $total_price = $orderedQty*$product_price;
       }
      $observer_model = Mage::getModel("tracker/observer");
      $observer_model->setName($customer_name)->setEmail($customer_email)->setProduct($product_name)->setStreet($address)->setCity($city)->setZip($zip)->setQuantity($orderedQty)->setTotalPrice($total_price)->setOrderDate($order_date)->save();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have calling the observer, So no need to call Model abstract class

**Mage_Core_Model_Abstract** at your class

So change `User_Tracker_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`

to `User_Tracker_Model_Observer`

**Also not required below code  at**

```
 public function _construct()
     {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('tracker/observer');
     }
```

Comment: how will my data get saved then in table? without extending Mage_Core_Model_Abstract. I have to save my data.

Comment: If a model ,have  ` model class` and `respective resource model class` then  `User_Tracker_Model_Tracker` and `User_Tracker_Model_Resource_Tracker `

Comment: then  when any call model factory then connection automatically call